# Shades of all the standard system colors from Human Interface Guideline

Tags: color, palette

I would like to leverage the might and convention of [Apple's standard colors](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/), however they only provide one shade per color. I would like to create about 10 shades per color for light and dark mode.

Has somebody made such a palette?

My initial thought was to convert the system colors to hsl and then apply increments of lightness. But I've heard hsl isn't that representative of human perception and also there's the complication of dark mode. Perhaps somebody knows of a standard way for generating shades of a color for light and dark mode?

Also I'm sure somebody must have done this before?

To be clear I'm looking for:

```
lightSystemRed0: {{ Some hex color value }}
lightSystemRed1
...
lightSystemRed8
lightSystemRed9
lightSystemBlue0
lightSystemBlue1
...
lightSystemBlue8
lightSystemBlue9
...
darkSystemRed0
darkSystemRed1
...
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I've removed the part of your question which asks for someone to make this for you, sorry about that. It's not really fair to ask for free work here.

Comment: Whats the problem? I mean sure i have made such a palette but how does thet help you?

Comment: Are you looking for software or some technique to automate this? Or do you just want to know how to alter the colours. To be fair, I don't see what's wrong with using HSL colour. You could adjust the L and S values by a set amount for each step. As long as the difference between the colours is distinguishable, it should be fine.